# Java Flight Recorder options not working and file is stored only in the end of the duration setting

Tags: java, parameters, profiling, jfr

I have a Java process and I start it (as suggested here : [parameters for FR](https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-4/jfr-runtime-guide/run.htm)) with the options :

-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:StartFlightRecording=duration=2m,filename=myflightrecord.jfr -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=maxsize=100k,maxage=1m

in order to have Flight Recorder information.

I would expect that the **maxage=1m** would give me only one minute of record, and **maxsize=100k** the file size wouldnt be larger than 100Kb, but none of them does work as expected.

Another problem that I encounter is that I want the file to be stored every amount of time, lets suppose every one minute. But the file "**myflightrecord.jfr**" is empty until the duration is reached (2minutes in the example).

Is there any way to make the Flight recorder flush before the end of the duration?

ps: The version of Java I am using is JDK1.8.0_45

Comment: FOR newer versions:

-XX:FlightRecorderOptions=disk=... has been removed. Use -XX:StartFlightRecording=disk=... instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maxage and maxsize options only apply when you have a continuous recording (= have not set duration). I also think that they are only guidelines, not exact limits.

If you want to get the data flushed to disk for a continuous recording, you can set disk=true, and if you want to specify where the data should end up, you can set repository=path
(I believe the data will only be flushed to disk when the the in memory buffers are full, I'm not sure if it's when the thread local buffers are full, or when the global buffers are full, see slide 13 in this slidedeck for a picture describing this: http://www.slideshare.net/marcushirt/java-mission-control-java-flight-recorder-deep-dive)

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html
XX:FlightRecorderOptions for more info. You can check the threadbuffersize and globalbuffersize as well.

I know the valid combinations of flags have varied a bit, so the documentation might not be entirely up to date.

[Kire Haglin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2049208/kire-haglin) can correct me where I've misunderstood things.

Comment: I tried the options that you suggested, but still didnt get anything. I will test again the parameters (probably duration is a parameter which doesn't combine with all the parameters?) and let you know! Thank you for the answer

Comment: As you might be able to tell from the verbosity of my answer, getting the JFR data continuously is not really a usecase that we support, so you will have to play around with flags etc to achieve it.

Comment: You can combine maxage, maxsize and duration, but most likely that is not what you want to do.

Answer (score 6):

This is for JDK 7 and JDK 8 (Hotspot), and JDK 5 and 6 (JRockit).

First, **maxsize** and **maxage** only works if you have a disk based recording, since the parameters controls how much data to keep on disk.

If you have an in-memory recording (**defaultrecording=true,disk=false**), the size of the memory buffers depends on the number of threads that are in use, how much memory each thread is allowed to use, number of global buffers etc.

Flight Recorder was designed for large servers with GB of memory and TB of disk, so I don't think the JVM will be able to respect the number you provided, i.e. a single event could be larger than 100 kb, but typically they are about 50-150 bytes.

Second, the name of the parameters (**maxsize** and **maxage**) are misleading. It's not the maximum size/age, but the threshold at which the JVM will remove a log file when they are rotated, which typically happens every 12 MB. To minimize overhead the JVM doesn't stop all the threads immediately when the threshold is met, which means  data spills over so in reality it is 12-15 MB. If the system is highly saturated, it could be a lot more, think 30-40 MB.

So setting the **maxsize** to 100k will not work, you will always get at least 12 Mb,

If you set the **maxage** to 1 minute you will get data for *at least* one minute, perhaps more if it can fit in the size of about one log file, 12-15 Mb.

If you have an in-memory recording, the data is copied from the memory buffers to disk when the recording ends. That's why your file is empty. If you want Flight Recorder to write continuously to disk, you should set **disk=true**.